# Aiogram получив от пользователя vin номер авто - проверить его по нескольким сайтам параллельно через Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, aiogram

```
@dp.message_handler()
async def echo1(message: types.Message):
    if len(message.text) !=17:
        await message.reply("Vin не верно ) ", parse_mode='markdown')

    elif (re.search('[а-яА-Я]', (message.text))):
        await message.reply("Vin не верно - кириллица!) ", parse_mode='markdown')
    else:  
        # тут код проверки 
        # -сайт 1
        # -сайт 2
        # -сайт 3
```

Сейчас бот проверяет присланный vin по трем сайтам **последовательно** и все устраивает - кроме времени на проверку.

Как реализовать, что бы он делал это в многопотоке , т.е открывал три окна Selenium **параллельно**, и не путался при одновременной проверке от нескольких пользователей?

*(выносил проверки в отдельные функции - но тогда он теряет текст присланный пользователем в рамках  dp.message_handler)*

Подскажите куда копать - Спасибо заранее.

Answer (score 1):

Если вы пишете на aiogram и задаете такие вопросы значит вы скорее всего не знаете про асинхронность. Почитайте про `asincio`.
Так же модуль `threading` в помощь. Но учтите, что в питоне есть такая штука как GIL, то есть потоки выполняются параллельно, но в одну единицу времени только один конкретный. Чтобы все работало совсем параллельно нужен `multiprocessing`, но касательно вашей задачи это как молотком муху убивать.
От себя могу еще добавить, что selenium будет быстрее всего работать с phantomJs, потому что он не будет открывать лишние окна.